# How Perform Domain Lookup Using Python script

Tags: python, lookup

How can I get information about a domain name (such as owner name and email) using  Python Script? 
I'd like to avoid using 3rd party web site.

Is this possible?

Is there is any special modules available for this.?

If anyone knows about this help me to get the result. Thank you

Comment: You mean using `whois`?

Comment: I don't know about the module. Is whois working well?

Comment: It's not a module, it's a little shell program to query whois databases. There are multiple python wrappers if you don't want to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

With using UNIX whois:

```
import subprocess
import re


def whois(ip,name):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['whois', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    m = re.search('{}:\s+[\d\w\@\.\ ]+'.format(name), out)
    return m.group(0)

print whois("213.180.204.3",'role')
print whois("213.180.204.3",'abuse-mailbox')
```

Output:

```
role:           Yandex LLC Network Operations
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@yandex.ru
```

Comment: It produce error like,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zz.py", line 12, in <module>
    print whois("213.180.204.3")
  File "zz.py", line 7, in whois
    p = subprocess.Popen(['whois', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/whois', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: I am using centos 6 and python 2.6.5. But gives same error. :(

Comment: run in console "whereis whois". And write output

Answer (score 0):

There sure is. The command you're looking for is called `whois`
Luckily for you python has a handy wrapper called `ipwhois`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipwhois

Be mindful that there is a certain limit to the amount of whois queries you can do on any given ip on any given day. You need to be a registrar for a higher quota, or use proxies. The first option would be cheaper though.

Alternatively you can take a look at https://whois.domaintools.com as well!